# Consume SOAP message in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, encoding, rpc

I have an old asmx web service which reads SOAP and send back data.
I am trying to convert the web service to WCF service.

The problem am having is that the request i am receiving is in RPC.Encoded format.
</ns1:create>
SPCR2023-00033-01application/pdffalse2023-03-16

...etc

In WCF,
I created the message contract
[MessageContract]
public class Document
{
[MessageBodyMember] public string[] Keys;
[MessageBodyMember] public string IdentifierDisplay;
[MessageBodyMember] public string contextType;....

The problem here is that it cannot read the request and getting object reference error.
string module = document.Keys[1];

But the wcf works in test client and soap.
The source cannot change their format.

What should I Change to make it work.
Is there a way to decode the soap and put it in the format WCF expects.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: <Document href="#id0"/></ns1:create>
<multiRef id="id0" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns2:Document" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns2="http://www.accela.com/edms/types"><Keys soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[3]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array"><Keys xsi:type="xsd:string"></Keys>
<DocumentLocators href="#id3"/>

Comment: Take a look at the solution in [this case](https://answers.sap.com/questions/11476917/wcf-webservice-with-rpcencoding.html).

Comment: That did not help any other reccomendation

Comment: What kind of binding did you use and it's better to post the app.config if you could. And the class [FaultContractAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.faultcontractattribute?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN) specifies one or more SOAP faults that are returned when a service operation encounters processing errors. This may help you locate the problem.